# Изменения кадров в Flash

Tags: flash

В Adobe Flash создаю проект, делаю там два ключевых кадра, на один кадр бросаю из библиотеки один MoveClip, даю ему имя и на второй кадр делаю тоже самое, кидаю тот же объект и даю то же имя, теперь, если я в AS обращаюсь на первый Moveclip, меню координаты, то и второй тоже меняет свои координаты, подскажите.

Как можно во Flash делать изменения в кадрах, чтобы это не несло последствий со следующими?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужны разные экземпляры мувика, самое простое - сделать дубликат в библиотеке.

**Дополнено.**

- программный код, выставляющий координаты для каждого кадра одному мувику (очень экономично)
- задать координаты мувика для каждого кадра в редакторе
- сделать правильно и красиво, код, работающий не с кадрами, а с временными промежутками, воспользоваться, например, какой-нибудь анимационной библиотекой - `TweenMax.to(mc1, 0.9, {x:newXPosition});` который работает с вашим массивом мувиков

Comment: А если их очень много надо?

Comment: Дополнено.

Comment: Суть не в количестве, при правильной организации кол-во влияет только на скорость выполнения. При создании мувиков запихиваете всех, например, в массив, и в нужные моменты дергаете из массива и присваиваете нужные координаты или что-то там еще. Помните, что флеш движок - не компилятор, он очень чувствительный к объему кода и объему данных, 30 раз в секунду менять координаты для 200 мувиков не лучшая идея.